# How to upload image with other data in retrofit

Tags: android, json, file-upload, retrofit2

User can get image from camera and gallery aslo user can crop image and setting in view working good.but after that i want to update it's profile with it's other data like "Name" ,"Number" etc.

by postman image is uploading successfully.
I tried multipart, way sending as file and also try to send as a string  but not getting successful or Failure response.i don't know what I m doing wrong. I m new in android please help if you can.

**Response and Get Structure**

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "profile_image": " ImageUrl will come here",
    "firstname": "Hamza",
    "lastname": "Ali",
    "email": "hamzaregardless333@gmail.com",
    "contact": "123455666",
    "gender": "Male",
    "location": "lahore"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you made a mistake because you didn't share your code.
I'm uploading image like below. Maybe it can help you.

Your Service

```
 public interface YourService {
        @Multipart
        @POST("api/exampleImageUpload")
        Call<YourResponse> uploadImage(
                @Part MultipartBody.Part image
        );
    }
```

Uploading Image

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("https://backendapi.com/")
       .build();
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("paramName","imageName",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));
    YourService iys = retrofit.create(YourService.class);
    Call<YourResponse> uploadCall = iys.uploadImage(filePart);
        uploadCall.enqueue(new Callback<YourResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<YourResponse> call, Response<YourResponse> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<YourResponse> call, Throwable t) {
              
            }
        });
```